# The value of my variable change

Tags: solidity, blockchain

I have two contracts (**A** and **B**) in the same smart contract. When I access from **B** to a **A's** variable the value is different that I can see from **A**.

For instance, when I access from **A** to that variable has a length equal to 2 If I have inserted two values but when I access from **B** the lenght of that variable has a different value.

Why?

Comment: Any snippets of code would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I initially want to think that you want to make sure you're accessing the right scope of that variable...But it's hard to say without code. I'll update my response if you can get some snippets of code.